# Variable from hash printing out surrounded with brackets and quotes

Tags: ruby, string, hash

The first line of code prints the string correctly.
However the same variable in the second line of code is surrounded with [""].  Why is that and how do I get rid of the surrounding quotes and brackets? `temp_hash[0][:item]` is from an array that holds hashes

```
 puts temp_hash[0][:item]
 puts "Sku is #{a} the amount sold is #{b} the name of the book is #{temp_hash[0][:item]} and the revenue per book is #{revenue.round(2)} "
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have an array in ruby: `arr = ["1"]` and do `puts arr` then the output will just be `1`. what type is `puts temp_hash[0][:item]`? It sounds like it's an array, try this:

`puts "Sku is #{a} the amount sold is #{b} the name of the book is #{temp_hash[0][:item].first} and the revenue per book is #{revenue.round(2)} "`

Comment: Sorry it is from an array of hashes

Comment: @Aaron yes but it sounds like temp_hash[0][:item] itself is an array, so instead of doing puts " #{temp_hash[0][:item]} " you should do puts "#{temp_hash[0][:item].first}"

Comment: Thanks, ruby is a little strange coming from a c++ background